# IllegalArgumentException, getter method of property, avoiding redundant data

Tags: java, hibernate, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to add new trip and place into database. There is relation between them many-to-one, so that one place can be assigned into many places. Place is adding correctly, but during adding trip there is this exception... 
I know there has been a lot similiar topics, but none of them helped me solving this problem.

```
ERROR: HHH000122: IllegalArgumentException in class: pl.th.java.biuro.hibernate.Place, getter method of property: idPlace
Exception found while adding new trip: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of pl.th.java.biuro.hibernate.Place.idPlace
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of pl.th.java.biuro.hibernate.Place.idPlace
at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:192)
```

Hibernate trip mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="pl.th.java.biuro.hibernate.Trip" table="Trip">
    <id column="idTrip" name="idTrip" type="int"/>
    <property column="date" name="date" type="date"/>
    <property column="cost" name="cost" type="int"/>
    <property column="profit" name="profit" type="int"/>
    <property column="organisator" name="organisator" type="string"/>
    <property column="period" name="period" type="int"/>
    <property column="food" name="food" type="string"/>
    <property column="transport" name="transport" type="string"/>
    <property column="persons" name="persons" type="int"/>
    <property column="kidsAmount" name="kidsAmount" type="int"/>
    <property column="idHotel" name="idHotel" type="int"/>
    <many-to-one name="idPlace" column="idPlace" class="pl.th.java.biuro.hibernate.Place" not-null="true" />
</class>
```

Hibernate place mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="pl.th.java.biuro.hibernate.Place" table="Place">
    <id column="idPlace" name="idPlace" type="int">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property column="country" name="country" type="string"/>
    <property column="city" name="city" type="string"/>
    <property column="island" name="island" type="string"/>
    <property column="information" name="information" type="string"/>
</class>
```

Trip class:

```
public class Trip {

private int idTrip;
private int idPlace;
private int idHotel;
private Date date;
private int cost;
private int profit;
private String organisator;
private int period;
private String food;
private String transport;
private int persons;
private int kidsAmount;

private String ownerName;
private String ownerLastName;

private Place place;

public Trip() {

}

public Trip(int idTrip, Date date, int cost, int profit, String organisator, int period, String food, String transport, int persons, int kidsAmount) {
    this.idTrip = idTrip;
    this.date = date;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.profit = profit;
    this.organisator = organisator;
    this.period = period;
    this.food = food;
    this.transport = transport;
    this.persons = persons;
    this.kidsAmount = kidsAmount;
}

public Trip(int idTrip, Date date, int cost, int profit, String organisator, int period, String food, String transport, int persons, int kidsAmount, String ownerName, String ownerLastName, Place place) {
    this.idTrip = idTrip;
    this.date = date;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.profit = profit;
    this.organisator = organisator;
    this.period = period;
    this.food = food;
    this.transport = transport;
    this.persons = persons;
    this.kidsAmount = kidsAmount;
    this.ownerName = ownerName;
    this.ownerLastName = ownerLastName;
    this.place = place;
}

/**
 * @return the idTrip
 */
public int getIdTrip() {
    return idTrip;
}

/**
 * @param idTrip the idTrip to set
 */
public void setIdTrip(int idTrip) {
    this.idTrip = idTrip;
}

    /**
 * @return the place
 */
public Place getPlace() {
    return place;
}

/**
 * @param place the place to set
 */
public void setPlace(Place place) {
    this.place = place;
}
And other get/set methods...
```

Place class:

```
public class Place {


private int idPlace;
private String country;
private String city;
private String island;
private String information;

public Place() {

}

public Place(String country, String city, String island, String information) {
    this.country = country;
    this.city = city;
    this.island = island;
    this.information = information;
}

/**
 * @return the idPlace
 */
public int getIdPlace() {
    return idPlace;
}

/**
 * @param idPlace the idPlace to set
 */
public void setIdPlace(int idPlace) {
    this.idPlace = idPlace;
}
```

**EDIT1**
Adding proper entities is working for me now, but I am wondering is there any way to avoid redundant data? For example, I add a trip and a place X connected with this trip. When I add another trip, but in this same place - X, this place is added again into my database. How can I avoid such action?

Comment: Have you instantiated idPlace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should chage the int idPlace int The Trip to your Object pl.th.java.biuro.hibernate.Place

Comment: This is not answer to question please post this type advices to comments

Comment: Yes it is answer to question, probably the DB generate the id bigger than int, so there is problem to set the id.

Comment: `ERROR: HHH000122: IllegalArgumentException in class: pl.th.java.biuro.hibernate.Place, getter method of property: idPlace` do you know preceding error mean in `Hibernate`?

Comment: Yes I know, it could be that long can't be inserted in to int without loose of information.

Comment: Please do not copy paste from my answer. If you trust you first answer is true why did you deleted?

Comment: You have +1 from me :)

Answer (score 5):

```
ERROR: HHH000122: IllegalArgumentException in class: pl.th.java.biuro.hibernate.Place, getter method of property: idPlace
```

I think you got this on insert operation. The preceding mean is that, you are inserting illegal argument to `idPlace` column. Your were using `many-to-one` with `pl.th.java.biuro.hibernate.Place` and insert an `int` as `pl.th.java.biuro.hibernate.Place`. You must change `idPlace` type from `int` to `pl.th.java.biuro.hibernate.Place`.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. A bit stuppid mistake but I will remember for future ;)